# cin and try/catch

Tags: c++, exception

I have this simple try catch for throwing cin exceptions, but it never throws exceptions.

```
while(cin>>num) {
   try {
      if(cin.fail()) {
         throw "error";
      }
      if(num>0) {
        cout << "number greater than 0" << endl;
      }
   }
   catch(char* error) {
      cout << error << endl;
   }
}
```

Why it is not throwing the exception?

Comment: This may be unrelated, but you should print errors to `cerr`, not `cout`.

Comment: Oh, and by the way.  Don't throw things that are not derived from std::exception please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cin >> num return false, so your loop body doesn't get executed at all.

If you really need to use execption

```
while(true)
{
    cin >> num;
    try{
       if(cin.fail()){
           throw "error";
       }
       if(num>0){
           cout<<"number greater than 0"<<endl;
       }
   }
   catch( char* error){
      cout<<error<<endl;
          break;
   }
}
```

It's better to put the try catch outside of the loop to get better performance

Comment: so, how do I make it to catch non-integer user input exceptions?

Comment: Good catch, I didn't even notice that.

Comment: Thank you for your help Phil. I am having one more issue now, I am taking the user input through redirected text file like:                   checknumber <input.txt   In this case, it is always throwing the error. Any suggestion?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what the problem is unless you provide more information. Maybe ask an new question

Answer (score 3):

String literals, like "error", do not match `char*`, it needs to be `const char*`

Comment: That doesn't throw an error during compilation? Or perhaps just a warning and the asker didn't have `-Wall` on?

Comment: @Andrew: I don't know why it would be an error.  He's not trying to call a function, it's just an uncaught exception.

Comment: Yea I suppose I just think an uncaught exception should be at least a warning because of type mismatches like this.

Comment: So, if I have it as const char* will it catch cin failures when the user tries to input non-integer values?

Comment: @user1035927: It would catch this particular exception, but as Phil pointed out, that loop body doesn't execute at all if there's bad input.

Comment: Yes, I was able to comprehend that, thanks to Phil. So, where do I put the try catch to catch the bad input exception...am confused